# Healer add-ons for end-game raiding in WoW?

Tags: world-of-warcraft, mods

As a followup to my [earlier question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/763/how-do-i-respec-from-dps-to-healing), what add-ons are available to assist healers in end-game raiding?  How do they work with limited screen real estate?  (I already use Skada, BadKitty, DBM, MikScrollingBattleText, TidyPlates and SexyCooldown)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Googling for [Healing Addon List](http://wow.curse.com/downloads/wow-addons/details/grid.aspx) the first result is a [question on EpicAdvice.com](http://epicadvice.com/questions/1500/healing-addons-list/1514#1514) with a pretty good accepted answer. I've quoted the answer below for reference.

From - [Healing Addons List](http://epicadvice.com/questions/1500/healing-addons-list/1514#1514)

> ### Raid frames
>
> **[Grid](http://wow.curse.com/downloads/wow-addons/details/grid.aspx)**  
>  "Grid is a modular, lightweight, and
>   screen-estate saving grid of
>   party/raid unit frames."
>
> A very good raid frame which is very
>   useful for healers. ([Clbull](http://epicadvice.com/questions/1500/healing-priest-addons/1503#1503))
>   Note: it can take a lot of fiddling to
>   set up how you like it, but lots of
>   tutorials exist for it and once you
>   get the hang of it, it's easy.
>   ([lilserf](http://epicadvice.com/questions/1500/healing-priest-addons/1505#1505))
>
> ### Click-bindings
>
> **[Clique](http://www.wowinterface.com/downloads/info5108-Clique.html)**   "Clique is a simple GUI that lets you assign click-casting
>   for any number of unit frames. Click
>   casting allows you to define the
>   behavior the game takes when you click
>   on a frame. This can be casting
>   spells, running a macro, using an
>   item, or something as simple as
>   changing targets or assisting a unit."
>
> Excellent when used with Grid to let
>   you bind various clicks (right, left,
>   middle, shift-left, etc) to different
>   spells. ([lilserf](http://epicadvice.com/questions/1500/healing-priest-addons/1505#1505))
>
> ### Cleansing
>
> **[Decursive](http://wow.curse.com/downloads/wow-addons/details/decursive.aspx)**   "Decursive is a cleansing mod intended to render
>   affliction removal easy, effective and
>   fun for all the classes having this
>   ability."
>
> I use Decursive, and I believe it (or
>   a similar addon) is not only helpful,
>   but **imperative**. ([Hhoky](http://epicadvice.com/questions/1500/healing-priest-addons/1524#1524))
>
> ### All-in-one
>
> **[VuhDo](http://wow.curse.com/downloads/wow-addons/details/vuhdo.aspx)**   "VuhDo is a raid monitor similar to CTRaidAssist or
>   Blizzards built-in raid frames.
>   Basically this is about displaying the
>   health of raid members in form of
>   clearly arranged bars. VuhDo is
>   primarily directed to healing classes,
>   but will make use to almost any other
>   class. Moreover several healing spells
>   or other actions can be asserted to
>   mouse clicks on those bars
>   (Click-Heal)."
>
> This is a solid replacement for Grid,
>   Clique, Healbot, what-have-you. Full
>   raid frames, ability to bind spells
>   (and Macros!) to key and mouse clicks
>   on those frames, integration with the
>   incoming heals libraries so you can
>   tell when someone is going to be fine
>   or not, ability to display HoTs
>   easily, and best of all -- it works
>   out of the box. Grid can take some
>   time to set up properly, but VuhDo
>   just works. ([Celairia](http://epicadvice.com/questions/1500/healing-priest-addons/1507#1507))
>
> ### Player versus Player
>
> **[Gladius](http://wow.curse.com/downloads/wow-addons/details/gladius.aspx)**   "Gladius adds enemy unit frames to arenas for easier
>   targeting and focusing. It is highly
>   configurable and you can disable most
>   features of this addon."
>
> Gladius is every arena player's dream.
>   Just like VuhDo it will run out of the
>   box; you can simply drag the window to
>   where you'd like and enter an arena.
>   However, if customisation is your
>   forté then there will be plenty to
>   keep you busy. In addition to the
>   usual Blizzard UI features of tracking
>   health/mana counts and spellcasting,
>   (albeit in a prettier way,) Gladius
>   tracks enemy trinket up/downtime and
>   drinking/first-aiding, as well as
>   several important buffs and cooldowns.
>   ([Roble](http://epicadvice.com/users/334/roble))
>
> ### Miscellanenous
>
> **[VisualHeal](http://wow.curse.com/downloads/wow-addons/details/visualheal.aspx)**   "VisualHeal is a small and simple but powerful tool
>   for all classes that visually shows
>   your heals to others and heals
>   incoming to you from others by means
>   of two information-packed, yet
>   intuitive bars."
>
> It shows all incoming heals to my
>   target (great for watching overheals,
>   or interrupting heals to maximize raid
>   healing). ([Hhoky](http://epicadvice.com/questions/1500/healing-priest-addons/1524#1524))
>
> **[SmartRes](http://www.curse.com/addons/wow/smartres2)**   "SmartRes puts bars on your screen that have timers
>   for the various resurection spells:
>   Resurrection, Ancestral Spirit,
>   Revive, Redemption, and tells you who
>   is casting on whom, how long it will
>   take to bring the target back to
>   life."
>
> I also use an incoming Rez addon,
>   called SmartRes, but that's just my
>   personal preference, to maximize
>   rez's. ([Hhoky](http://epicadvice.com/questions/1500/healing-priest-addons/1524#1524))
>
> ### Class-specific
>
> **[PoMTracker](http://www.wowinterface.com/downloads/info11925-PrayerofMendingTrackerPoMTracker.html)**   "A mod that tracks who Prayer of Mending is
>   jumping to and how many charges you
>   have left. Displaying it in a small
>   movable window frame." ([Hhoky](http://epicadvice.com/questions/1500/healing-priest-addons/1524#1524))

Hope it helps!

Comment: VuhDo sounds promising.  :)

Comment: Grid + Clique is brilliant combo. I couldn't live without it. The strength of Grid is its customizing options - if you master it, you won't want to use anything else.

Comment: +1 for Grid + Clique. I can play my Holy paladin entirely with only my mouse hand, no keyboard. Especially great if you have a mouse with a lot of buttons!

Answer (score 8):

For me the best one is Healbot.

Shammy Healer here.

Comment: I've heard good things about heallium as well, or some such. But I loves me my healbot.

Comment: As a resto druid, I'm a Healbot user as well.

Comment: Holy Pally/Resto Druid, and I use healbot.

Comment: Where do I find 'healbot?' In other words: Is it the same as 'healbot continued?'

Comment: That's right, it is the same.

Answer (score 2):

One thing I haven't seen in this list that I find pretty useful is a HoT timer.  My current pick is [ForteExorcist](http://wow.curse.com/downloads/wow-addons/details/fortexorcist.aspx).  That's nice when you want to know how much time is left on your Regrowth or such.  It'll track most time related stuff: HoTs, DoTs, CDs, debuffs.

For a buffing addon (not directly related to healing), I'm currently using [ZOMGBuffs](http://wow.curse.com/downloads/wow-addons/details/zomgbuffs.aspx). It's pretty well configured out of the box, and it binds to the mousewheel when out of combat for easy buffing (really handy if you're a pally), but only if you (or someone in your group) is missing a configured buff.  It'll pick up the short term temp buffs like Hysteria (Blood DK talent) as well, and give you a separate button to trigger those (as well as targeting the last person it was used on).

Comment: In regards to HoT timers, there's also an addon for Grid called GridRaidStatusHoTs or GridRaidHoTStatus (I can't get the link at the moment). It's nice to not have to have yet another UI element to look at if you're already using Grid as your raid frames. I will endorse ForteExorcist though, as I use it for it's cooldown bar, which is especially useful for short CDs like Prayer of Mending and Penance/CoH (guess what I play?).

Answer (score 1):

For me, the obvious choice is [Pitbull4](http://wow.curse.com/downloads/wow-addons/details/pitbull4.aspx), with it's near-infinite costumizability.

The only thing it doesn't do is click-casting, which I hate anyway, but you can probably use Clique with it.

Here's a couple of screenshots:

[1](http://i100.photobucket.com/albums/m17/Jurily/WoW/WoWScrnShot_060410_141817.jpg) (It doesn't show here, but for dead, offline and AFK players, their status shows up below their name. All displayed text can be seperately scripted in Lua.)

[2](http://i100.photobucket.com/albums/m17/Jurily/WoW/WoWScrnShot_051610_193511.jpg) (Range fader in action, for hunters it's trade range I think.)

[3](http://i100.photobucket.com/albums/m17/Jurily/WoW/WoWScrnShot_012410_151220.jpg) (You're not restricted to a grid view, like in some other addons.)

[4](http://i100.photobucket.com/albums/m17/Jurily/WoWScrnShot_042510_165204.jpg) (Grid-like, with names trimmed to 5 characters.)

[5](http://i100.photobucket.com/albums/m17/Jurily/WoW/WoWScrnShot_013110_214049.jpg) (There's a debuff on me I could dispel, it shows up in the border by default.)

Also highly recommended, but not on the screenshots: [Inline Aura](http://wow.curse.com/downloads/wow-addons/details/inline-aura.aspx), [OmniCC](http://wow.curse.com/downloads/wow-addons/details/omni-cc.aspx) and [!Cooldown Fader](http://wow.curse.com/downloads/wow-addons/details/cooldown-fader.aspx), which make looking at your action bar buttons fun.

Comment: What action bar manager do you use?

Comment: [Bartender4](http://wow.curse.com/downloads/wow-addons/details/bartender4.aspx).

Comment: I already use OmniCC (didn't list it above since it doesn't affect screen real estate...).  Also, it looks like you use both Skada and Omen?

Comment: Omen is much more configurable when it comes to threat monitoring.

Answer (score 1):

I do endgame healing on my Tree, I assume you're also druid becaue you've got BadKitty installed.

I use the following addons:

- oUF_freebgrid - Simple and works with default configuration
- Clique - Click healing. Works with all raid frames.
- DBM - Indispensable
- Recount

That's all I need for healing. I have other addons, but none are relevant to raiding. oUF_freebgrid will show curses/poisons you can remove, watch for the debuff icon and apply the correct dispell.

oUF_freebgrid Also shows you a countdown for your rejuv, a little smiley face of varying dispositions for your lifebloom, and green dots to show regrowth/wild growth active on your target. (Assuming Resto Druid of course). This isn't entirely intuitive, but you get to know which pixels mean what pretty quickly when you're dancing around the raid giving out HOTs like candy.

I find recount to be incredibly useful, you're using Skada which is equivilent. I use the healing meters to know if I'm pulling my weight with heals. I bind lower and uppercase J to DPS vs. Healing meters. I watch DPS so I know who to battle-res - who cares if a sub-par DPS dies, but if the 15k DPS rogue has bought the farm I'm going to stand him back up.

Answer (score 1):

I would really recommend vudoh! It's basically a combination of all the other healer addons (healbot / grid / clique / decursive) in one.

It's completely customizable and allows you to setup different configs based on group size. It has built-in click-to-cast functionality, or you can use mouse-over macros. You can show group members and there targets.

Click-to-cast also recognizes enemies, so you can cast harmful spells on them.

It also has a great buffing panel. It will show how many in the group are buffed, missing buffs, or low (only for buffs you can provide). To buff, just click the icon.

Has a built in range finder and aggro detector. Has panels for assigned tanks and assists and you can have your own private tanks.

Answer (score 1):

Between X-Perl Raidframes and blizzard's macros, I don't need anything else.

X-Perl has a lot of options to tell me all I may wish to know about when I'm healing.

I use macros that cast healing spells on friendlies and damage spells on enemies - depending on what I'm targeting. Then I can switch to my second bar (shift-2) to use the same macros in mouseover versions. Add a mouse with extra buttons bound to the number keys, and I can do one-hand healing. And often do.

(For reference, in 5-mans, I can one-hand any standard (l200) 80 heroic with my keyboard as well; I had to do *something* to keep it challenging when I got badly overgeared. Even foul tanks rarely mess things up unless I'm healing from elemental spec.)